# Best way to Create Reports in the server by C# and ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, extjs, report, asp.net-core-6.0

I am currently developing an accounting application using ExtJs (Front-End) and C# with ASP.NET Core 6 to generate JSON APIs as (Back-End)

but I stuck on generating the reports in the server

- Should I Use Microsoft Word as a template and generate PDF
- Should I play with HTML in the server and generate the reports
- Or Use a report server (I don't yet have experience on this)
- Or any other Ideal !!

what is the best way to generate reports on the server?

Please note:

- SSRS is not an option because I am not using SQL Server
- Report Data Source will not be a direct database connection, data have to be manipulated in the server (by C#) first before arriving to report builder

Comment: If your architecture separated to frontend and backend, i think design report in frontend side and return data from backend. Then maybe call report design page with http request. View too: https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4256/visual-studio-report-designer

https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/web-report-designer/overview#:~:text=Telerik%20Web%20Report%20Designer%20is,in%20an%20HTML5%20Report%20Viewer.

Comment: I prefer to generate the report in the server to have full control over it

Comment: It would be good if you could use any report viewer. If it is not suitable for you then you could try to fetch the data from your DB and try to generate report using HTML or any reporting library. Using MS Word to generate PDF will not be the best approach here to generate reports.

Answer (score 3):

I'd either go with a web view of the data or generate PDFs on the backend. Sounds like you want a backend solution, so if you go with PDFs you can use something like [QuestPDF](https://You%20could%20use%20something%20like%20QuestPDF%20to%20generate%20a%20PDF.%20You%20can%20just%20take%20your%20data%20structures%20and%20it%27ll%20take%20a%20bit%20of%20work%20to%20get%20the%20spacing%20right,%20but%20if%20you%20want%20to%20have%20PDF%20reports,%20it%27s%20probably%20the%20best%20free%20and%20open%20source%20solution%20I%27ve%20seen.).

Any PDF generation tool takes a bit of tweaking to get the spacing and pagination right for your need, but once you have it, you can modify it how you need for different reports without too much trouble.

Other report solutions I've seen are too expensive or annoying to work with, so if you don't have super complex reporting needs that a specific paid solution is really good for, I'd use QuestPDF.

Comment: which solution do you will be better. Creating Microsoft Word Document and manipulating it with tools like (Syncfusion Document Processing) and generate PDF, or Directly working with PDF vis (QuestPDF).  I have good experience working with documents with (Syncfusion Document Processing 'Word')

Comment: It's hard for me to say. You have the domain knowledge, so I'd do a quick proof of concept using both and see which one is a less annoying workflow. Depending on what you're using it for, you have to pay for Syncfusion unless your company generates less than $1m in revenue and has 5 or less developers.